# Multiclass target detection : N X (1 vs all) or 1 X (N vs all)?

Tags: neural-network, classification, deep-learning

I am doing a multiclass classification using neural networks.  Say I have 10 target classes and one null (non-of-the-above-targets).  Is it better that I train a neural network separately for each target with two output neurons for each network (target , non-target) so that i would need 10 separate neural networks in the case above or a neural network with 11 outputs (10 targets, 1 other)?  I have seen people using either of the two approaches in different papers but without explanation, but is there a theoretical superiority to using a separate network for each target class?  Is the computational overhead cost worth the gain and benefit with respect to the alternative approach ?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. (1) Of course in either of the approaches the distribution of training examples is heavily skewed towards the non-target ("other") class, and (2) The output layer of the NN is assumed to have a softmax activation.

Comment: I'm not sure what programming question is contained here. Seems more like a computer science theory question. Especially better with what regard?

Comment: Well, of course better performance wise, in terms of generalization error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you could potentially tackle a problem like this:

**Train a Single Network with Separate Class Outputs**

This approach would likely be the quickest to train and design, and would have a number of outputs equal to the number of class outputs desired.  On the flip side, you would need to ensure that there are enough cases for each class in the training set to prevent the neural network from favoring certain classes above others.  Additionally, the network would not be specialised for individual classes as the next case would do.

**Train a Network that specialises in a specific class**

In this case, N Neural Networks would be trained with likely half true and half false cases.  Each Neural Network would be evaluated with testing data and a class selected based on the outputs of each individual network.  There is about N times more training as well as preprocessing of training data, but also a likelihood that accuracy would be increased overall.  Whether the computational cost is justified by the accuracy improvement is up to the designer, but you should generally see an improvement.

**Build a Modular Neural Network that trains on groups of closely related classes**

Here, you could potentially split the 10 groups into two groups of five, depending on which neural network is considered best for the testing case.  Here, you could train one network to assign a specialist neural network and train two others to estimate specific classes.  This is a kind of midway point between the above two.

There are many other approaches that could work too, but these are the main three that come to mind based on the question outlined above.